# How to get latest patch of a Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, semantic-versioning

I have following syntax in my `requirements.yaml`

```
# umbrella/requirements.yaml
dependencies:
  - name: my-chart
    version: ~1.0
    repository: "@my-repo"
```

I want to receive all the patches of `my-chart` every time I run `helm dependency update`. However, it seems to work only if I have release versions like `1.0.8`, `1.0.12`, etc. in `my-repo`. But not for snapshots, e.g. `1.0.13-SNAPSHOT`

> Error: Can't get a valid version for repositories `umbrella`

Is that an expected behavior or how should I fix this?

Comment: is the `1.0.13-SNAPSHOT` visible in repo's index.yaml?

Comment: Yes. I can do helm fetch my-repo my-chart --devel

Comment: Does the same happen when you keep the naming convention- `1.0.13.SNAP` instead of `1.0.13-SNAPSHOT`?